# how to fetch data from local ip with external host origin by chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I wanted to fetch data from local IP with Angular framework by chrome browser. but chrome browser blocked this request. and I not found any solution for solve this problem . please help me

Comment: what is your error and http code ? please provide your request and response in your question

Answer (score 2):

That is CORS issue, you can set response header to allow cross-origin access

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: thanks for you, but this problem not CORS issue, because this request failed in chrome browser and not response any error message